# What is the most appropriate way to cache arbitrary data in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, caching

I would like to cache some arbitrary data in my iOS app. I would like it to remain in memory for as long as possible, and fall back to long-term storage if the "in-memory" cache is going away (app is closing). Also, I would like the older items to get pushed to long-term storage once the "in-memory" cache fills up with newer, more-frequently-accessed items.

What libraries or frameworks would I need to use to add this functionality?

Comment: `NSUserDefault` for storing small amount like config, setting..., `CoreData` , `Realm` for storing object and everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really enjoyed using [TMCache](https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache) although it seems to not be maintained anymore. It has in memory and disk cache and a very good performance.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Looks like Pinterest forked the library and released their own called PINCache.

Comment: Good to know! Will check as well.